# Alcoholic RootBeer

Tags: beginner, wheat-beer, root-beer

My Goal is to make a root beer with a ABV similar to your everyday beer or maybe stronger. (4-10%) I am newer to homebrewing so most of my experience comes from using Kits. My approach was going to be to use a Wheat Beer Kit (ABV 5.2%) and before starting the Fermentation process I would add some Root beer extract.
Any suggestions or Tips would be Greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you like your root beer, but to get a taste similar to commercial root beers, you'll need a completely different recipe.

Here is a related question: 
[How would I make Alcoholic Rootbeer?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/565/how-would-i-make-alcoholic-rootbeer)